# Compare many CSV files to get Ranks

Tags: r, csv, statistics

I have many `csv` files that contain daily product sales ranked by position

**Sale_2018_04_10.csv:**

```
position    Products
    1          product_a
    2          product_b
    3          product_c
    4          product_d
```

**Sale_2018_04_11.csv:**

```
position    Products
    1          product_c
    2          product_d
    3          product_a
    4          product_b
```

What I need is to show `Sale_2018_04_11.csv` file with rank change compared to last one `Sale_2018_04_10.csv`, e.g.:

```
position    Products         Rank change
    1          product_c         +2
    2          product_d         +2
    3          product_a         -2
    4          product_b         -2
```

I can do this manually between 2 or 3 files, but I receive these files daily, in many categories.

My question is: what is the best solution to manage these files with ranks?

**Update :** 
- Should I save all the files in one Database and then generate a new report daily? please help

NB: I'm using a linux server

Thank you!!

Comment: Previous position - Today position = Change... Ideally, use some dataframe object like R or Pandas. You don't need Hadoop

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. does every daily file contain every file?  Or will product_b sometimes be missing because it has zero sales?  2. Do you envisage having a master reporting file that pulls in the data from the CSVs and produces a report?

Comment: @CFO 1- yes some products will be missed (not only 0 sales) from the daily report 2- yes this the best thing to have, but not a priority

Comment: So the master reporting file will need to hold all product codes.  The user types the report date into a cell and runs the macro.  The macro opens the files for that date and the day before, looks up the data for each product code and closes them again.  Could also look up 7 days earlier, year earlier, etc.  Will need error trapping in case of missing files

Comment: Thank you @CFO yes this is best solution but i dont like to li use Macro's + Excel because my data are stored in a linux server, and i try to keep all the work there.